# How to load PCL's App class from Win Phone 8.1 RT project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.winphone

I'd created a Windows Phone 8.1 Project into an existing Xamarin Forms solution (Android, iOS and UWP). I'd followed instructions from Xamarin Documentation pages, but still unable to find "LoadApplication()" method. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and the Project has .NET Framework 4.5 on her profile.
The Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT namespace hasn't the necessary class.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create windows phone 8.1 client project following ["Adding a Windows Phone App"](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/phone/). It is working pretty well. You may miss some key procedure.

I have tested if you miss step two(right-click on the newly created project...)and step five(Edit MainPage.xaml...) in the article mentioned above, you will unable to find `LoadApplication()` method.

The [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/AddNewClientProjectTest.git) has uploaded to github,You could refer to my code sample and verify difference between this two. So that you could find the missing procedure.

Comment: Hi Mr. @Nico Zhu - MSFT. Thanks for your answer. Actually I followed the same tutorial, and, reviewing your code sample, they are equals. When I copy and paste your code
 'LoadApplication(new EllevoMobile.App());
  this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;' the Intellisense not show any error, but, when I try to write the 'LoadApplication()' method, it's not found by Intellisense. I have a print screen to show it, but don't know how to add it here in Stackoverflow.

Comment: I have encountered similar problems in  the low version of the `Xamarin`. But it does affect the application running. You could try to update [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/download) component for Visual Studio.

Comment: Currently I'm using Xamarin 4.4.0.34 and Xamarin Forms 2.3.4.224, all of them are last stable version until this moment.